# Multiple files copied to Windows corrupted, each appear to fill HDD free space

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, filesystem-corruption

I am facing an issue where pictures copied from a Samsung smartphone (Android) to a PC have somehow been corrupted. The pictures are in JPG format, and appear as such in the folder they were copied to. But each picture displays a size of approx. 32GB, and it is impossible to open the pictures (timeout/file size too bid/file corrupted error messages, depending on software used). All files taken together give a total size of approx. 7TB, on a 120GB hard disk which still shows 30GB free.

Since the files have been copied to the PC, it is showing performance issues (slowed down). And I am worried that it may be a sign of, or a cause of, file-system corruption.

What I believe happened is that each time the file was written to the hard disk, that it didn't properly close the file (or terminate the entry in the file allocation table), and that it carried on into the hard drive's free space. This is, however, just an educated guess on my part.

**Is there a way to either correct the file corruption (have the files correctly terminate in the file system), or have a tool that is able to take the file and recover the image using the information in the JPEG file header?**

The files have been deleted from the phone (I know there are some possibilities to recover the photos from the phone, that is not the point of this question).

Operating system: Windows 10 Home edition.

**Edit:** following the suggestion of using Ifranview 64-bit, it was unable to. It gave the error message "Can't read file header ! Unknown file format, empty/damaged file or file not found !"

Comment: What is your specific Question?

Comment: @Moab Edited to explicitely ask (rather than imply): Is there a way to either correct the file corruption (have the files correctly terminate in the file system), or have a tool that is able to take the file and recover the image using the information in the JPEG file header?

Answer (score 0):

**First make an image of the HDD in case repair and error checking does harm.**

You might try [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) or an [alternative tool](https://alternativeto.net/software/recuva/). My use of recovery tools has not often been been successful, but hopefully you'll fare better.

You might do better accessing the HDD while you boot from USB with tools such as [SystemRescueCD or Ultimate Boot CD](https://techtalk.gfi.com/top-5-free-rescue-discs-for-your-sys-admin-toolkit/).

In any case, the safest thing to try would be to use the Windows Disk Error Checking tool. It will likely *not* recover the JPG files, but might repair the damage to the partition.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open *Explorer*.
- Right-click on the drive containing the JPEG images.
- On the `Tools` tab select the `Check` button.
- Perform a complete scan to check for errors and hope for the best.

Comment: Yes, a friend brought Recuva to my attention. I'll check it out.